# How can I add toggle buttons for navbar items for mobile screen and toggle them for dropdown menu using HTML, CSS and Bootstrap v4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm displaying the drop down menu on hover in the navigation bar for desktop display, but for it to be responsive I would like to add a button to the right of the navigation menu on the mobile screen and use it to toggle the drop down menu on and off.

Screenshot of what I'm looking for, a toggle button for dropdown menu for mobile screens:
[image: Screenshot of what I'm looking for, a toggle button for dropdown menu for mobile screens]

Here is my code:

```css
.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}
.navbar{
  padding: .8rem; 
}




.navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}


.cart {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:none;
}
.navbar-nav li:first-child{
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {    

.navbar {
border-radius: 4px;
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-brand{
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.navbar-nav li:not(:first-child){
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.navbar-nav li:first-child{
    display: block;
}


#myNavbarToggler13 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: inherit;
}

.nav-item{
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 5px 35px 0px;
    /*margin: 5px 0 0 50px;*/
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" role="navigation">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#myNavbarToggler13"
      aria-controls="myNavbarToggler13" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
<a class="navbar-nav navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><img id="logo">Brand
  <button class="cart" type="button" data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#cartToggler"
      aria-controls="cartToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="cartToggle navigation">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M8 1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.5 2.5V4h-5v-.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 8 1zm3.5 3v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V4H1v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h-3.5z"/>
  </svg>
  </button>
</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbarToggler13">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="crossButton" href="#">X</a>
          </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="index.html" id="navbarDropdown">item 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 3</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 4</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 5</a>
      </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="index.html" id="navbarDropdown">item 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 3</a>
      </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="index.html" id="navbarDropdown">item 3</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 2</a>

      </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="cartToggler">

  </div>
</nav>
<script>
    $(".navbar-toggler ").on('click', function() {
        $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
        $navMenuCont.animate({
            'width': 'toggle'
        }, 350);
        $(".menu-overlay").fadeIn(500);
    });
    $(".menu-overlay").click(function(event) {
        $(".navbar-toggler").trigger("click");
        $(".menu-overlay").fadeOut(500);
    });
    $("#crossButton").click(function(event) {
        $(".navbar-toggler").trigger("click");
        $(".menu-overlay").fadeOut(500);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `parent`, `siblings` and `children` selector and toggle the display for the elements like you wish.

**Note:** In order to make it work you have to remove `href` for the dropdown toggle element, else it will take you to another page

Example below

```js
$(".navbar-toggler ").on('click', function() {
    $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
    $navMenuCont.animate({
        'width': 'toggle'
    }, 350);
    $(".menu-overlay").fadeIn(500);
});
$(".menu-overlay").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-toggler").trigger("click");
    $(".menu-overlay").fadeOut(500);
});
$("#crossButton").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-toggler").trigger("click");
    $(".menu-overlay").fadeOut(500);
});

$('.nav-item .nav-link').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().siblings('li').children('.dropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

```css
.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}
.navbar{
  padding: .8rem; 
}




.navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}


.cart {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:none;
}
.navbar-nav li:first-child{
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
border-radius: 4px;
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

  .navbar-brand{
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

.navbar-nav li:not(:first-child){
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.navbar-nav li:first-child{
    display: block;
}


#myNavbarToggler13 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: inherit;
}

.nav-item{
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 5px 35px 0px;
    /*margin: 5px 0 0 50px;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" role="navigation">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#myNavbarToggler13"
    aria-controls="myNavbarToggler13" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-nav navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><img id="logo">Brand
    <button class="cart" type="button" data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#cartToggler"
    aria-controls="cartToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="cartToggle navigation">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.5 2.5V4h-5v-.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 8 1zm3.5 3v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V4H1v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h-3.5z"/>
    </svg>
    </button>
</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbarToggler13">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="crossButton" href="#">X</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown">item 1</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" >subitem 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="">subitem 2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="">subitem 3</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="">subitem 4</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="">subitem 5</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown">item 2</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown">item 3</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">subitem 2</a>
                
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="cartToggler">

</div>
</nav>
```

jQuery reference for siblings: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

jQuery reference for parent  : https://api.jquery.com/parents/

jQuery reference for children: https://api.jquery.com/children/